# Export Segmentation Labels from LabelBox tool

Tags: data-annotations

I used LabelBox tool to annotate my segmentation dataset. It has the option to export as .json or .csv file. I am unable to convert the exported .json file into standard coco format to use it in MaskRCNN training.

Any idea how to convert LabelBox exported .json or .csv file into standard coco format?

PS: I have already tried LBExporters library but it gives Key Error "geometry".

Answer (score 0):

MaskRCNN uses the VGG image Annotator format and not the standard coco format. I also thought that it would use the coco format but when I tried it did not work. After some research it appears that MaskRCNN only uses the coco weights for the initial weights but uses the VGG image Annotator format for the labels.

To convert the Labelbox JSON to VGG image Annotator format, so it is usable for MaskRCNN, I wrote a small program: https://github.com/SamRutten2000/Labelbox_converter.

There is also a Labelbox to coco and Labelbox to yolov5 format converter at the repository.